# Printing combinations from generated factors from an integer

Tags: python, list, combinations

My goal is to generate triples of factors, in all possible combinations
for instance:

```
# For 6, all factors combinations of 6.
        (1, 1, 6)
        (1, 2, 3)
        (1, 3, 2)
        (1, 6, 1)
        (2, 1, 3)
        (2, 3, 1)
        (3, 1, 2)
        (3, 2, 1)
        (6, 1, 1)
```

As you can see positioning of integers do not matter.

```
num = 6
print(num)
for i in range(1, num+1):
    if(num % i) == 0:
        print(i, end=' ')


def factors(L):
    for m in range(3):
        for n in range(3):
            for p in range(3):

                if (m != n and n != p and m != p):
                    print(factors[m], factors[n], factors[p])
```

Comment: But you did not tell us your problem :)

Comment: Do you want to optimize it?

Comment: It's giving me an error, of course because it's not in the right format.

Comment: Why didn't you add the error log in your question ? the same problem , you did not tell us about the error. :)

Comment: Start with a basic Python tutorial.  This code gives the impression that you're copying and pasting bits of code you've seen elsewhere without understanding how they work; you won't get to a working solution that way, and coming up with all the factors of a number in an efficient way isn't a suitable problem for a beginner anyway IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments above, the error is in this line:

```
print(factors[m], factors[n], factors[p])
```

You are treating `factors` as a list or an array, whereas it is a function. You should call it like that `factors()`.